# iptables-save fails to write to file

Tags: linux, iptables, centos6

I can run iptables-save and dump output to stdout but if I redirect to a file - the file is empty:

```
    [root@nhd-vlx2 tmp]# iptables-save  
    # Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Sun Dec 18 15:11:42 2011
    *filter
    :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
    :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [90971:17757587]
    -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9090:9999 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
    -A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
    COMMIT
    # Completed on Sun Dec 18 15:11:42 2011
    [root@nhd-vlx2 tmp]# iptables-save  > save
    [root@nhd-vlx2 tmp]# cat save
    [root@nhd-vlx2 tmp]# 
    [root@nhd-vlx2 tmp]#
```

Piping works (`iptables-save | cat`), and so saving to file through `tee` works too, but why would `iptables-save` not allows saving to a file?

The only reason I can think is that this machine may be infected by a virus (an attempt to weaken a firewall)

Comment: let me guess - Red Hat/CentOS?

Comment: Centos6,  this used to be fine on centos5  (but as you suggest, maybe selinux s getting in the way)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Long shot, but:

Somebody else posted a similar problem in another forum. As it turns out, the SELinux context is wrong.

Run ls -laZ on iptables-multi. It should return with:

```
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:iptables_exec_t:s0 /sbin/iptables-multi
```

All the other iptables files are symlinked to it:

```
[root@cacti tmp]# ls -laZ /sbin/iptables*
lrwxrwxrwx. root root system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0       /sbin/iptables -> iptables-multi
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:iptables_exec_t:s0 /sbin/iptables-multi
lrwxrwxrwx. root root system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0       /sbin/iptables-restore -> iptables-multi
lrwxrwxrwx. root root system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0       /sbin/iptables-save -> iptables-multi
```

If the SELinux context is not correct, change it with the chcon command on the main file:

```
chcon -u system_u -t iptables_exec_t /sbin/iptables-multi
```

If the SELinux context on the symlinks are not correct, fix them using the above command (although this time with the bin_t type)

Comment: As far as I can tell the output was the same as yours: `rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:iptables_exec_t:s0 /sbin/iptables-multi` ... and the symlinks also look the same `lrwxrwxrwx. root root system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0       /sbin/iptables-save -> iptables-multi`

Comment: Disabling selinux wth `echo 0 >/selinux/enforce` makes `iptables-save`  behave as expected ... so what is selinux trying to save me from?

Comment: The default behavior of selinux wouldn't cause this. You mentioned that this used to be Centos 5 - was this an upgrade or a complete rebuild?

Comment: At any event, I would probably suggest do a cat on /var/log/audit/audit.log and pipe it to audit2allow to see if it notices anything odd when you attempted to save iptables-save to file with a redirect

Comment: This a fresh install of Centos6 seen both on a VM and a machine that was formatted+installed.  (2) I may have mislead a little, its quite possible that I have disabled selinux on my Centos5.5 host. (3) audit2allow shows `allow iptables_t vmblock_t:file write;`

Comment: Number 3 is the core problem. Run it again, but this time with -M as an option with audit2allow. Then from there, you can install it with semodule (In fact, it will give you the exact command).

Comment: Created module with -M, installed (tried both semodule -i & system-config-selinux), still, `iptables-save > save ; cat save` produces nothing unless `selinux` is disabled

Comment: While this answer did not solve my issue, it definitely seems like it contains the rights steps so I have decided to accept it. There must be some other variable at play.

Answer (score 0):

As per Rilindo comment, if you are on RedHat the [docs](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sect-Security_Guide-IPTables-Saving_IPTables_Rules.html) mention:

```
~]# /sbin/service iptables save 
iptables: Saving firewall rules to /etc/sysconfig/iptables:[  OK  ]
```

Comment: service iptables save is a wrapper around iptables-save. The difference is that you can use iptables-save to write to any file, while service iptables save writes to /etc/sysconfig/iptables-save and /etc/sysconfig/iptables by default.

Comment: @Rilindo - Yes, I understand but this would tell us if the iptables is totally ok (which sounds like it is as tee/cat work just redirection fails). So could the shell be globbing the command somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The iptables-save tries to set the correct selinux security context on a minimalistic centos-7.

I looked at the error, and it appears to fail because the utilities for changing selinux context are not installed (via dependency?).

The following fixed it for me:

```
yum -y install policycoreutils
```

After this, the following worked okay:

```
/sbin/service iptables save
```

Comment: The question was about the `iptables-save` executable.

Comment: yes - and iptables-save will fail if policycoreutils is missing (tested on centos 7)